# How to replace values in a data frame with the header?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

In a data frame, I wish to use R to replace all values in a column > 0 with the column header, from this:

```
d1 d2 d3 d4  
R1  0  1  0     
R2  0  0  1
R3  1  0  0
```

to this:

```
d1 d2 d3 d4  
R1  0 d3  0     
R2  0  0 d4
R3 d2  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in a single step with

```
df[-1] <-  replace(df[-1], df[-1] == 1, rep(names(df[-1]), colSums(df[-1])))
```

---

Or using `ifelse`

```
df[-1] <- ifelse(df[-1] ==1 , names(df)[-1][col(df[-1])], 0)
```

-output

```
df
#  d1 d2 d3 d4
#1 R1  0 d3  0
#2 R2  0  0 d4
#3 R3 d2  0  0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(d1 = c("R1", "R2", "R3"), d2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), 
    d3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L), d4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE` to get row and column index where value is greater than 0. Use the column index to replace those values with column names.

```
mat <- which(df[-1] > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
df[-1][mat] <- names(df)[-1][mat[, 2]]
df

#  d1 d2 d3 d4
#1 R1  0 d3  0
#2 R2  0  0 d4
#3 R3 d2  0  0
```

---

We can also use `Map` :

```
df[-1] <- Map(function(x, y) replace(x, x > 0, y), df[-1], names(df[-1]))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(d1 = c("R1", "R2", "R3"), d2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), d3 = c(1L, 0L,
 0L), d4 = c(0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Then I get a closure error: "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"......

Comment: OK, I fixed an error in my script which made the data frame unrecognisable as a data frame, and I ran your code, but it did not produce any of the desired changes - all 1s are still there. 

Maybe my importation is wrong? This is how the first three rows/cols look like:


OTU_ID 100_Mycena_vitilis 102_Mycena_galopus 10383_Mycena_latifolia
OTUITS1_tjek_1 1 0 0
OTUITS1_tjek_10 0 0 0
OTUITS1_tjek_100 0 0 0

I import it like this: df<-read.table("mydataframe.txt", header = T, row.names = 1).

Comment: @ChristofferBuggeHarder Can you add `dput(head(df))` to your question?